# RSA signature with restricted range of $d$

Tags: rsa, signature

My question is:
Alice signs messages using RSA with a public key $(e,N)$ and a private key $d$. Alice chooses $d$ in the range $N^{0.25} < d < N^{0.5}$.

What is the time needed for Alice to calculate the signature $S = m^d \bmod N$?

My answer is: Alice chooses $e$ so that $d$ is in the range $N^ {0.25} < d < N^ {0.5}$. Since $d$ is in the range $N^ {0.25} < d < N^ {0.5}$, we have $d = O(N ^ {0.5})$. Therefore, the time needed for Alice to calculate the signature $S = m ^ d \mod N$ is $O(\log d) = O(\log (N ^ {0.5}))$.

But I am not sure.. can anybody help??

Answer (score 1):

> Alice chooses $d$ in the range $N^{0.25}<d<N^{0.5}$.

That's unwise, at least for the low range of this interval: Boneh and Durfee's [*Cryptanalysis of RSA with Private Key $d$ Less than $N^{0.292}$*](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-48910-X_1) may allow an attack.

> What is the time needed for Alice to calculate the signature $S=m^d\bmod N$?

Given $N$, $m$ with $0\le m<N$, and $d>0$, we can compute $S=m^d\bmod N$ as follows:

- $S:=m$
- for each bit $b$ in the binary expression of $d$, starting from the second highest-order bit down to the least significant bit:

  - $S:=S^2\bmod N$
  - if bit $b$ is set then $S:=m\,S\bmod N$

For essentially uniform choice of $d$ in the range $N^{0.25}<d<N^{0.5}$, this has cost about proportional to the bit length of $d$, that is to $\|d\|=\lceil\log_2(d+1)\rceil$. Choosing $d$ such that $N^{0.25}<d<N^{0.5}$ makes $\|d\|$ about $\|N\|/4$ to $\|N\|/2$, rather than typically within few bits of $\|N\|$ in modern textbook RSA¹.

Thus **having $N^{0.25}<d<N^{0.5}$ reduces the work to compute $S$ by a factor like $2$ to $4$.**

If we want to express the cost as a big-O expression of $N$, we need to consider the cost of modular squaring and modular multiplication as $N$ grows. When using  elementary algorithms, that's $\mathcal O(\log(N)^2)$ (this can be lowered to to $\mathcal O(\log(N)^{\log_23})=\mathcal O(\log(N)^{1.585…})$ by [Karastuba multiplication](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-48910-X_1), and further in theory but not in cryptographic practice). It follows the total cost to compute $S$ is $\mathcal O(\log(N)^3)$ (or $\mathcal O(\log(N)^{2.585…})$ with Karatsuba). That big-O expression is not changed by having $N^{0.25}<d<N^{0.5}$ compared to standard choice of $d$, since the gain is by a constant factor.

A common, significant saving comes from using the Chinese Remainder Theorem: with $N=p\,q$ (and $p$ and $q$ distinct primes, thus $\gcd(p,q)=1$), it's computed $S_p=S\bmod p$ as $m^{e^{-1}\bmod(p-1)}\bmod p$, and $S_q=S\bmod q$ as $m^{e^{-1}\bmod(q-1)}\bmod q$. Then the final $S$ is obtained as $S=((S_p-S_q)\,q^{-1}\bmod p)\,q+S_q$. With precomputation of $d_p=e^{-1}\bmod(p-1)$, $d_q=e^{-1}\bmod(q-1)$, and $q_\text{Inv}=q^{-1}\bmod p$, the saving approaches a factor of $4$ (or $3$ with Karatsuba). The big-O expression is not changed. There's no longer any gain in having $N^{0.25}<d<N^{0.5}$, making this pointless, beyond being a possible security issue.

---

¹ Modern textbook RSA typically considers $N$ the product of two large random secret distinct primes $p$ and $q$, so that the [Euler totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_totient) is $\Phi(N)=(p-1)(q-1)$; moderate public exponent $e>1$ such that $\gcd(e,\Phi(N))=1$; and private exponent $d:=e^{-1}\bmod\Phi(N)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! Not obvious at all.
I would like to raise another point with you -
Given the range of d specified in the question, I am asked to attack the algorithm.
I thought of using brute force since the range of d is bounded by a finite number
Does that make sense to you? Or you would use a different algorithm to find out d.

Comment: Making an attack given the range of $d$ is a different question. Before going into brute force for $d$, count how many $d$ you'd likely have to examine, and forecast the duration of that. Compare to factorization of $N$ by state of the art methods, and to the attack I link to at the beginning of this answer (which is not guaranteed to work).

Comment: thank u so much! I didn't quite understand the complexity - is the complexity log(n) or n*log(n)

Comment: @dana: I had the complexity wrong! It's $\mathcal O(\log(N))$ modular squarings/multiplications, thus $\mathcal O(\log(N)^3)$ counting fixed-word operations with standard algorithms.